# How do I deserialize a list with double entitiy names?

Tags: xml

I have the xml listed below.  I would like to deserialize to a list<> in C#.  Is there a way to deal with the doubleing up of the list entity names ASIwizard and Wizard?  If it were just ASIwizard or Wizard I can do it but I'm not sure what to do if each element has a double entitiy name?

```
<ASiwizards>
  <ASiwizard>
    <Wizard>
      <id>1</id>
      <title>Headlight Wizard</title>
      <description>This wizard will help troubleshoot issues related to the headlight functionality of the eBike controller</description>
      <created>2012-04-27 14:35:34</created>
      <modified>2012-04-27 14:35:34</modified>
    </Wizard>
  </ASiwizard>
  <ASiwizard>
    <Wizard>
      <id>2</id>
      <title>Wiring Harness</title>
      <description/>
      <created>2012-04-27 19:11:33</created>
      <modified>2012-04-27 19:11:33</modified>
      </Wizard>
  </ASiwizard>
</ASiwizards>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var items = xElement
  .Elements("ASiwizard")
  .Select(x => x.Element("Wizard"))
  .Select(
    x => new {
      Id = (Int32) x.Element("id"),
      Title = (String) x.Element("title"),
      Description = (String) x.Element("description"),
      Created = (DateTime) x.Element("created"),
      Modified = (DateTime) x.Element("modified")
    }
  )
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you know what I would add to this                                                                    public class ASiwizards
    {
        [XmlElement("Wizard")]
        public List<WizardList.Wizard> Wizards;
    }                                                                namespace WizardList
{
    public class Wizard
    {
        public int id;

        public String title;

        public String description;
    }
}

Comment: @DonRobb: You should update your question to clarify it. It seems that you want to use `XmlSerializer` and you should also add the snippet you wrote in the comment. I will probably have to delete my answer.